# How to prevent distributing vertically over whole page in Lyx?

Tags: formatting, lyx, vertical-alignment, koma-script

I work with the documentclass book (koma-script) in Lyx. In the final pdf, all text, pictures, etc., are distributed vertically over the whole page. I prefer to put them on the page from the top with no additional spaces between. An example here:

[image]

How can that be fixed? I prefer to include something in the Lyx preamble that will be valid for the whole document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

write into `Document->Setting->Preamble` the commands

```
\raggedbottom
\setlength\@fptop{0\p@}% float at the top
```

Comment: Thank you! worked very good for text. How to manage that floating figures are not placed in the center of an empty page but on top?

Comment: see my edited answer